# What is the consensus, if it exists, on the (absence of) biological effects of artificial sweeteners?

Tags: food, nutrition, toxicology, food-chemistry

I tried to Google (and PubMed) the question, but it seems to be fairly polarized debate and there does not seem to be a consensus as to whether sweeteners like asparatme, acesulfame etc. have meaningful biological effects.

Some studies point to molecular effect with little to no explanations about their relevance for health, and since statistical significance and size effects are quite different things, question remains unanswered.

Comment: If the scientific research papers can't provide a clear answer to this, then likely there is no consensus effect known. Whether this is interpreted that as 'no actual effect whatsoever' or 'we have't looked deep enough' is up to you I guess.

Comment: I remember checking out a lot of papers on the subject at some point and most of them report a slightly impaired glucose intake insuline response as the only side effect of chronic artificial sweeteners consumption. Also another conclusion was soda with these sweeteners does help weight loss but not as much as not drinking any kind of soda at all. I can try to search for the papers later again